# Changing DataGridview after filter combobox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I'm trying to refill my DataGridView after a filter selection in a combobox. 
Here is my code where I try...at this moment the code is clearing the DataGridview and just fill only on row with only 1 cell..KlantID = 7

Any idea?

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectionChangeCommitted
    klantid = ComboBox1.SelectedValue

    Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection
    Dim DBpath As String = "C:\Facturatie\CharelIjs.accdb"
    Dim sConnectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & DBpath & ";Persist Security Info=True"
    myConnection = New OleDbConnection(sConnectionString)
    myConnection.Open()
    Dim SQLstr As String
    SQLstr = "SELECT * FROM tblKlant WHERE KlantID = @klantid"


    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(SQLstr, myConnection)
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim ds As New DataSet()

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@klantid", OleDbType.VarChar)
    cmd.Parameters(0).Value = klantid
    Try
        da.Fill(ds, "tblKlant")
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Can't load Web page" & vbCrLf & ex.Message)
        Return
    End Try

    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds
    DataGridView1.DataMember = "tblKlant"
    DataGridView1.Refresh()
End Sub
```

Comment: it shows one row because your SQL selects one row (`WHERE KlantID = @klantid`).  Also, it looks like you might be doing a type conversion from int to varchar with it.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you populating records on every `combobox_SelectionChange` event execution. Try to filter your data only instead of query execution.

And, better to use `SelectedValueChanged` event instead of `SelectionChange`.

```
Private Sub form_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    //Fill your data here with DataView
    Dim myConnection As OleDbConnection
    Dim DBpath As String = "C:\Facturatie\CharelIjs.accdb"
    Dim sConnectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & DBpath & ";Persist Security Info=True"
    myConnection = New OleDbConnection(sConnectionString)
    myConnection.Open()


    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM tblKlant", myConnection)
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim dt As New DataTable() 'Dont use dataset if your are not relating more than one tables

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@klantid", OleDbType.VarChar)
    cmd.Parameters(0).Value = klantid
    Try
        da.Fill(dt)
        dt.TableName = "tblKlant"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt.DefaultView
        DataGridView1.DataMember = "tblKlant"
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Can't load Web page" & vbCrLf & ex.Message)
        Return
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub combobox_SelectedValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles combobox.SelectedValueChanged
    IF combobox.SelectedValue IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim dv As DataView = DirectCast(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataView)
        dv.RowFilter = "KlantID=" + combobox.SelectedValue.ToString()
    Else
        dv.RowFilter = vbNullString
    End IF
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think you understand my problem. I'm just filling my combobox1 in my load part + my datagridview with a Dataset.
After a filtering change of the comboBox, I want to adapt the data from the gridview so it will only shows 'rows' from that client. 
Full code of page here: http://pastebin.com/M96tTCQE

Comment: Do you mean by want to show only one cell in your datagridview?

Comment: No I just want to show all data from that specific client selected in the comboxbox. The combobox is just a simple filter element, to just find all the records of a client instead of all records from every client

Comment: Have you tried my given example...? That will filter your records in the datagridview as per selected value in your combobox.

Comment: I already tried it but no success..But in your example where do you fill the combobox with all 'Klant' data? As you can see in my full code, the datagridview is filled thanks to a dataset object...so to fill it in Load, it was just one line.

Comment: The grid will be populated on form load.. Now, you just need to filter the data only. So, when you assign the filter string into the DataView object your grid will be filtered with given criteria. You should read about `DataView.RowFilter` on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter(v=vs.110).aspx)